# Rate of convergence of $n^x$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, convergence-divergence, rate-of-convergence

> Rate of convergence of $r_n = n^x$ dependent on the parameter $x$.

$r_{n+1}=(n+1)^x = n^x+xn^{x-1}+o(n)$

$lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{r_{n+1}}{r_n} = lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^x+xn^{x-1}+o(n)}{n^x} = lim_{n\to \infty}1+\frac{x}{n}+o(n)/{n^x} = 1$

So the rate of convergence is sublinear in both $x \in (0,1)$; $x \ge 1$ and $x < 0$ cases?

Comment: I suggest that you do not use $a$ as a variable.

Comment: In addition, what you are doing only makes sense for $-1 < n < 1$.

Comment: @TobyMak I have $n>0$. Can you provide a more detailed answer?